# ASP C# Wizard post-back issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, wizard, autopostback

I'm using a wizard as in the below image [image]

In the 6th wizard i have to upload a document, after uploading page post back to the first wizard!
I tried many solutions as below:

1. Using an update panel
2. Using `$("#wizardDiv").load(location.href + " #wizardDiv");`
3. Using

   `$("#li-allPrevDiv").attr("class", "active");
    $("#allPrevDiv").attr("class", "tab-pane");`

and for the one i need to be active (the 6th wizard)

```
$("#li-wizardDiv").attr("class", "active");
$("#wizardDiv").attr("class", "tab-pane");
```

none of the above worked for me! looking forward for your help..

Comment: are you navigating the wizard using javascript??? then then javascript is reloaded on every postback. save the wizrard number to a variable or a hidden field then after post back check the variable and make the function go directly to that tab/wizaard. for 6th tab save 6 in a hidden field and your navigation function should check this hidden field and move to the wizard according to the number

Comment: thanks for your reply.. i tried this also but it didn't work, i used `$("#wizardDiv").load(location.href + " #wizardDiv");` am i writing it right?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I had to work on all previous wizrds (enabling them) then on load `$("#wizardDiv").load(location.href + " #wizardDiv");`

For sure i had to add a flag to tell me where the user was before reloading